# Dblclick на паренте и click на дочернем элементе

Tags: jquery

Как отследить двойные и одиночные клики по элементам?
У меня есть поле

```
<table>
 <tr><td class="dblclick">

   <table>
    <tr><td class="click"></td></tr> 
    <tr><td class="click"></td></tr>
   </table>

 </td></tr>
</table>

 $(".dblclick").on("dblclick", function(){
     ....
 });
```

Если писать еще и:

```
 $(".click").on("click", function(){
     ....
 });
```

, то он не срабатывает. Срабатывает только первый, dblclick.

По одному и тому же элементу я умею, но мне нужно чтобы был dblclick на паренте, и click в ячейках вложенной таблицы. Вложенная таблица строится динамически.

**UPD**

Вопрос решен. Ответ [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/214148/jquery-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-on-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Comment: Перенес ваш пример на [jsfiddle][1], вроде как надо работает (если я правильно понял вопрос).  
P.S. у вас в заголовке даблклик на дочернем элементе, а в коде на предке.

  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/vCbjP/

Comment: Я же написал, что вложенная таблица динамическая... Если динамическая, то не работает.