# Не работает .on на загруженный элемент аяксом

Tags: jquery

Открываю .dialog() загружаю в него аяксом элемент:

```
<a class="edit">edit</a>

$(".edit").on("click",function(){
    alert();
});
```

Не срабатывает. Вешаю alert(), никакой реакции.

Comment: почитайте немного [теории](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126471/), разберетесь быстро

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вешайте обработчик на какой-нибудь родительский элемент, который уже есть, например `body`

```
$('body').on('click','.edit',function(){
    alert();
});
```

Comment: все никак от .live() не могу отвыкнуть

Comment: До сих пор не могу понять в чем разница между .on и .live.

Comment: @Dem - live - это та штука которую использовать нельзя. а on это та что ее заменяет (грубо говоря, на самом деле сейчас bind это алиаc на on)

Comment: @eicto, я бы даже уточнил. Метод **.on()**, как бы объединяет функционал трёх устаревших методов: **.bind()**, **.delegate()** и **.live()**. Если сравнивать с **live()**, то механизм **.on()** более логичен, т.к. дает возможность делегированной обработки событий. Если **.live()** "шерстил" весь документ, в поиске нового/динамически добавленного элемента, то при методе **.on()** - этот круг сужается, за счет того, что мы ему указываем статический элемент, внутри которого и необходимо произвести поиск.

Comment: О, теперь понятнее, благодарю!